# How do I create horror-like glitchy horizontal motion blur effect on object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, post-processing

I am not sure what the effect is called and I do not seem to find anyway to find out either. You can check out the effect here in a game called Layers of Fear:

- https://youtu.be/Lvls-TH0uVU?t=18m37s <-- the crying ghost
- https://youtu.be/Lvls-TH0uVU?t=14m8s <--the bottle of whiskey in the lower left of the screen
- https://youtu.be/Lvls-TH0uVU?t=16m50s <--the ghost as it's walking around

I know it's done by using shaders but can anyone link me to a guide to achieve it or the effect's name? Would love to add something like that in my game!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably wont be able to find anything for such advanced effects. Even if you pay for some library, its not likely to include this one in particular. You'll have to do some trial-and-error and experiment with stuff, and maybe you could make that tutorial yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do most of these with [Unity Effects](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-ImageEffects.html). All of the effects used are only available for Pro users only. You need a license to be able to use those or you will have to write them by yourself.

You can write your own **Image Effects** with 
[OnRenderImage](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WritingImageEffects.html) but that will be complicated.

You have to do everything below as a timer, in `coroutine` with `Time.deltaTime` instead of `yield return new WaitForSeconds()`.

**FIRST VIDEO EFFECTS**:

[Tilt Shift Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-TiltShiftHdr.html)

[Twirl Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Twirl.html)

[Blur (Optimized)Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-BlurOptimized.html)

[Edge Detect Effect Normals Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-EdgeDetectEffectNormals.html)

[Color Correction Ramp Texture Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ColorCorrectionRamp.html) Modify the RGB Ramp Offset from code.

Repeatedly **Change** the **opaque/transparency** of the character/3D Model from 0-1, through code.

**SECOND VIDEO EFFECTS**:

[Grayscale Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Grayscale.html)

[Twirl Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Twirl.html)

Use code to change **Radius**,**Angle** and **Center** properties of the [Twirl Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Twirl.html).

**THIRD VIDEO EFFECTS**:

Turn lights on/off repeatedly

[Color Correction Curves Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ColorCorrectionCurves.html) Apply this while turning the light on/off.

When going down the elevator, apply [Motion Blur Effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-MotionBlur.html) while modifying its **Blur Amount** and **Extra Blur** properties.

Comment: What's this talk of unity-pro? You don't need a pro license for any of these.

Comment: I appreciate the whole explanation! Really resourceful but the effect I am looking for is not the Image Effects applied to the camera. I wanted to know the effect that happens to the ghosts or bottle itself. It looks like  as if the ghost/bottle dissolves into lines or twiches violently and then comes back together very quickly. That's the effect I am looking for. Also, I do posses a Unity Pro License

Comment: @Doug, Last time I used Image Effects Pro was required. The tutorials said I needed Pro. The Unity website said I must have Pro license to use Image Effcts. This was version 4.xxx. Here, just read that http://docs.unity3d.com/400/Documentation/Components/script-TwirlEffect.html . I don't know if this has changed as I use pro now and can't verify that.

Comment: @ChaosEmperor93 I am a programmer and a visual effects artist and I can tell you that those effects in the videos are many effects combined together. Its not one or two. many of them. Unity does not have a single effect to accomplish that. They provided what is needed to get that look by combining them together and then changing their properties during runtime to make them look animated. " twiches violently"- I mentioned something about opaque/transparency with code that should do it. I beleive there is an Image effect that can turn things into lines.

Comment: I don't remember if that is part of standard ones or not but you can search for one online to do the dissolves into lines stuff. Just like I mentioned above Unity effects can do most and if not 90 percent of the stuff in the video and if you look close, you can see that those are multiple effects not one and most effects can be scaled to match the shape of your object and some of these requires scripting to make them work properly.

Comment: @Programmer While that may have been true in the past, it is not any more. You no longer need pro for this; just add the standard assets from the asset store; they are covered by the same license as the other assets on the asset store.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks a lot for your help! I'll have a go at it and hopefully manage to accomplish it. :)

Comment: As for what @Doug is saying, it is true since the release of Unity 5. Image Effects no longer require a Pro License

Comment: Just modified the answer to remove the Pro license part. Unity made lots of changes for v5 release but I didn't know about this one. I just watched that video again and I came to conclusion that unity can do all of this with the image effects and little bit of code that constantly modifies the values of the image effects. You have to experiment with them. Good luck.